# Is it ok to setup my AVFoundation camera in a singleton?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, avfoundation

I have made a custom camera using AVFoundation. After extensive testing and research, I came up with a solution to make my camera extremely fast to load when going to the camViewController. The solution is to do have the setup of my camera inside a func inside a singleton. The function gets called on viewDidLoad() of my base view controller. Then when the user presses the button I do a segue to the camViewController where I set up my preview layer. I never pause the capture session after I segue back to the base view controller.

I have been kind of worried/afraid of using this solution due to the dangers I sometimes hear/read about online. Thus: what are the drawbacks of doing this (memory/performance issues? etc.), or should I completely steer away from implementing this solution? Thanks!

Comment: Dfg, there are indeed ways to program a camera system in iOS, so that, it "comes up quickly" - you're definitely on the right track.  (And you can do that, without, burning battery.)  However that issue, makes no difference at all whether you use a singleton or not.  There are a number of other ways you can "hold" (to phrase it generally) that functionality.  In general there's nothing wrong with using singletons in iOS development (particularly given that ........ basically everything in  iOS is a singleton .. "the app", screen, compass, etc etc); FWIW I don't in the situation you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have problems with an application review by Apple.
To start capture session, you should ask permission to the user, but [apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/) to ask permission only if the app clearly needs it. I do not think that in your case, the user will clearly understand why the launched application (without camera on the current screen) asks permission to access the camera. (I think you can try to send the application with such feature to the application review).
The second problem is more serious (I think): while capture session is active, iPhone spends more power. This is not very good for battery life. [Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/index.html) use battery in most efficient way.

Comment: There's no problem, whatever, for asking with permissions when the app launches (many/most of the biggest apps do exactly that, it's fine.)  Note that this issue is very minor/irrelevant (if you did, or did not, use the proposed singleton approach, you could as you preferred ask the user at any particular time about the permissions.)

Comment: Yes, in this reason I think that @dfgdfgdfgdfg can try to send the application to an application review. It all depends on an auditor.

Comment: Honestly, Apple don't mind if you ask **on startup**. The visual example they give on that link of the Nike app, does ask on startup.  It clearly **states** "Users won’t be bothered by this request [at startup] if it’s obvious that your app depends on their personal information to operate."

Comment: (Also, using or not using a singleton, makes no difference at all to the issue of when the permissions box appears.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at how other apps deal with this situation.

I've tried Instagram and it looks like there is a small delay **after** the user enters the `View` with the camera. They probably instantiate the `captureSession` in `ViewDidAppear`, this way there isn't any slow down during the navigation.

Them they freeze the `View` that just appeared until the `captureSession` is ready, so the user will have some feedback of what is happening on the app and there won't be need to keep the session in memory the whole time (which will for sure use more resources from the device).